# How to embed YouTube videos in Power BI while avoiding cross-origin or other issues?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I attempted to embed a YouTube video in Power BI Desktop using 'Html Content' visual as shown in the image below. But it didn't work.

[image]

After publishing the report to Power BI Service and opening it in a browser, I encountered the error in the browser console as shown in the second image.

[image]

Seeking a functional solution.

Answer (score 1):

To embed YouTube videos in Power BI please refer this documentation:
https://www.discoverei.com/blog/how-to-embed-videos-in-power-bi

Also, refer to this Microsoft Community Forum discussion:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Embedded-Youtube-Video-in-Dashboard-auto-play/m-p/1741670/highlight/true#M124211